# Can i use the error functionality of jquery ajax call to a ext js ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, extjs

In my application there are two types of ajax calls.

1.Ext js ajax calls. 
2.Jquery ajax calls.

following are two code samples for each of them.

1.Ext js ajax calls.

```
Ext.get(document.body).mask('Processing...', 'x-mask-loading');
    searchURL = getFormAction('hm.web.HMCaregiverManager', 'getCountryKeyTx');
    var conn = new Ext.data.Connection();
    conn.request({
        url: searchURL,
        method: 'POST',
        params: {"hm_caregiver_country_uno"  : countryUno
                },
        success: function(responseObject) {

            var countryKeyTx  = responseObject.responseText;
            initCountryDropDowns(countryKeyTx);

            Ext.get(document.body).unmask(true);

        },
         failure: function() {
             Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Unable to contact server');
             Ext.get(document.body).unmask(true);
         }
    });
```

2.Jquery ajax calls.

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: validateAjaxURL,
                success: function (data) {                  
                    var returnData = data;  
                    if (returnData.match("^selectedUno-")) {    

                          $('#new_caregiver_popup_div').dialog('close');    
                    }else{
                        $("#new_caregiver_popup_div").html(data);
                    }
                },
                error: function (jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    handleAjaxError(jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);                        
                }
        });
```

I am using "jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown" parameters in jquery ajax call error: option in order to get details about the error. And i want to get error details of the ext js ajax call's failure too. So can i include that error function instead of the ext js ajax call's failure function. Then code will be like this.

```
Ext.get(document.body).mask('Processing...', 'x-mask-loading');
    searchURL = getFormAction('hm.web.HMCaregiverManager', 'getCountryKeyTx');
    var conn = new Ext.data.Connection();
    conn.request({
        url: searchURL,
        method: 'POST',
        params: {"hm_caregiver_country_uno"  : countryUno
                },
        success: function(responseObject) {

            var countryKeyTx  = responseObject.responseText;
            initCountryDropDowns(countryKeyTx);

            Ext.get(document.body).unmask(true);

        },
         **failure: function (jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    handleAjaxError(jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);                        
                }**
    });
```

will this ext js ajax code work?any help will be grateful.

Comment: Well, have you tried it? Did it work? The [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection) states that both success and failure have 2 parameters.

Comment: no i didn't try it.how can i get failure details using those parameters of failure?

Comment: Umm.. look in the browser console what properties they have? I don't understand why you don't just try it.

Answer (score 2):

In extjs all request are ajax. The class responsible for that is Ext.Ajax

Here is the api:
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.3/Ext.Ajax.html#method-request

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'ajax_demo/sample.json',
    success: function(response, opts) {
        var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        console.dir(obj);
    },
    failure: function(response, opts) {
        console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
    }
});
```

Failure function has two parameters:

```
failure :  Function
    The function to be called upon failure of the request. The callback is passed the following parameters:

    response :  Object
        The XMLHttpRequest object containing the response data.
    options :  Object
        The parameter to the request call.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. if an ajax error(internal server error,parsererror,file not found etc) occures, can i identify those using response, opts parameters?

Comment: Sure. All properties are described here: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_http.asp)